# what type of guitar scale is this?

Tags: guitar, scales

There is an mmorpg (game) where playing a guitar is possible, i want to know if this guitar scale or type relates anything to guitars in the real world

[image]

here's how C1 sounds : http://picosong.com/ESVu/

Comment: here's how B3 sounds http://picosong.com/ESVz/

Comment: The notes correspond more closely to a piano or other keyboard instrument than a guitar.  Same notes on guitar and piano but the octave numbers are more closely associated with keyboard instruments.

Comment: @RockinCowboy I'd argue that the layout is more guitar like than piano like as it looks like a fretboard. The numbers jus mark the octave which we can write out a for a guitar just as easily as piano.

Comment: The 3rd string of a ukulele is normally tuned from C4 (open) to C5 (12th fret)

Comment: @Dom Actually I don't think it looks like a keyboard OR a fretboard (even though it looks like a board). I based my assessment on the fact that guitarist rarely refer to octave numbers the way pianist do. Probably because it would be useless in describing position.  A C4 is near the middle of an 88 key piano and a C5 is to the right and C3 to the left of C4.  With guitar - the note which corresponds to C4 can be played in several different places on a guitar fretboard.   But whoever created the game may have intentionally made it ambiguous so it could apply to any chromatic instrument

Answer (score 3):

It's just 3 octaves of [the chromatic scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_scale). Based on what you say it sounds like it is not the scale, but the range given to compose in. The game is just giving you the range from C1 to B3 to play with to create / make music.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the connection between the chart picture and the sound file, but the sequence...

C, C#, D, D#, E, F, F#, G, G#, A, A#, B

... is the chromatic scale.

The numbers next to the letters look to me to be "scientific pitch notation" 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation